# PHP downloading file from server opens file instead of downloading

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been practicing saving file names in Mysql and downloading file from server using the `GET` method. Uploading works fine but when downloading file from folder the file opens automatically it will not download.
This my code to download file from folder

```
<?php
include 'includes/ann.php';
// connect to the database
$username = "uname"; 
$password = "pass"; 
$database = "practice5";
$servername = "localhost";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM documents";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$myfile = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);


// Downloads files

if (isset($_GET['docum_id'])) {
    $ids = $_GET['docum_id'];


    // fetch file to download from database
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM documents WHERE id=$ids";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $file = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $filepath = 'docs/' . $file['name'];
    if (file_exists($filepath)) {
        ob_start();
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octetstream');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filepath) . '"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate,post-check=0, pre-check=0');
         header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('docs/' . $file['name']));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile('docs/' . $file['name']);
        exit();
}
else
{
    echo "No files found";
}
}
?>


 <div style="margin-top: 100px;" class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
          <h2 style="text-align: center">Download</h2>
          <table id="example" class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr class="bg-warning">
               <th><?php echo $lang['tableheadOne']?></th>
                <th><?php echo $lang['murtiletit']?></th>
                <th><?php echo $lang['murtiledesc']?></th>


              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <?php foreach ($myfile as $file): ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $file['id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $file['title']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $file['description']; ?>
                    <a href="checkFile.php?docum_id=<?php echo $file['id'] ?>"><?php echo $lang['download']?></a></td>


                  </tr>

                 <?php endforeach;?>

                  </tbody>
              </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div
    ..footer
```

The above code works well on localhost but on server it doesn't work it opens corrupted files as soon as I click the download button. Thanks

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Add download attribute to link

```
<a href="checkFile.php?docum_id=<?php echo $file['id'] ?>" download><?php echo $lang['download']?></a>
```

It will tell the browser to load instead of opening

Comment: And i think, you can just provide path to file in link, and and keep files in public folder

Comment: If you don't need to generate file or change it, just put in link path to file. I don't thik, that you need use headers in script.

Comment: <a href="/path/to/file.extension"><?php echo $lang['download']?></a></td>

Comment: @ Minatula Shakhbazov what if i have multiple files? is exposing path safe?

Comment: From my experience: usually files for download are put in a public folder(for example uploads, same situation with css files, they are stored in public folders). From this folder you can download files by direct link, on your page you can generate links with paths to these files. I didn't try to make multiple downloads(not sure, that browser will let you do it).

Comment: Is that file is a PDF